# Select single column from a row in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How can I fetch a single column from a single row in Laravel 4?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
return DB::selectOne("
    SELECT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM permissions p
            JOIN role_permissions rp ON rp.permission_id=p.id
            JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.role_id=rp.role_id
        WHERE ur.user_id=? AND p.code=?
    )
    ",[Auth::user()->id,$perm_code]);
```

`selectOne` returns this ugly object though:

```
object(stdClass)#297 (1) {
  ["EXISTS(
                SELECT *
                FROM permissions p
                    JOIN role_permissions rp ON rp.permission_id=p.id
                    JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.role_id=rp.role_id
                WHERE ur.user_id=? AND p.code=?
      "]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

Is there something better?

---

Using PDO is ugly too:

```
$stmt = DB::getPdo()->prepare("
    SELECT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM permissions p
            JOIN role_permissions rp ON rp.permission_id=p.id
            JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.role_id=rp.role_id
        WHERE ur.user_id=? AND p.code=?
    )
    ");
$stmt->execute([Auth::user()->id,$perm_code]);
return (bool)$stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: i don't know if laravel has `selectOne` method. 2nd, the above sqlwill  always return just one row with either true or false.

Comment: @itachi Laravel does have a selectOne method, but it returns one row, not one column. It returns an object, with a stupidly named property (the entire query) unless I give it an alias, and then pull it out of there, which I can do of course, was just looking for something cleaner.

Comment: let me guess, your issue is, you don't want to fetch but directly get the bool result. right? cz using an alias will solve it easily.

Comment: Answer to your question is `pluck`, but you definitely need to alias the column as it's DB thing that resulting column, using `exists`, has name of the entire query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch a single value from the first result, you can use `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::value`. e.g.

```
$lastInvoice = DB::table('booking_groups')
    ->where('company_id','=',$booking->company_id)
    ->orderBy('invoice_number','desc')
    ->value('invoice_number');
```

Answer (score 23):

Use this:

```
DB::table('users')->pluck('columname');
```

From the inline documentation:

```
/**
 * Pluck a single column's value from the first result of a query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @return mixed
 */
```

Comment: Can you show this with a where clause @Kurt Beheydt ?

Comment: Add ->first() to actually get the value rather than a collection;

Comment: In Laravel 5.2 this fetches the entire column.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
DB::table('users')->select('columnName')->join('whatever',...,...,...)->take(1)->get();
```

Another example

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('columnName')
            ->take(1)
            ->get();
```

Raw didn't worked for you?:

```
return DB::select(DB::raw("
    SELECT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM permissions p
            JOIN role_permissions rp ON rp.permission_id=p.id
            JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.role_id=rp.role_id
        WHERE ur.user_id=? AND p.code=?
    ))
    ",[Auth::user()->id,$perm_code]);
```

And you can process that object to get what you want:

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw("
    SELECT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM permissions p
            JOIN role_permissions rp ON rp.permission_id=p.id
            JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.role_id=rp.role_id
        WHERE ur.user_id=? AND p.code=?
    ) as exists)
    ",[Auth::user()->id,$perm_code]);

$result[0]->exists ? '1' : '0'
```

This is a test I just did here:

```
Route::any('test', ['as' => 'test', function()
{

    $result = DB::select(DB::raw('select exists(select * from users) as  exists;'));

    dd($result[0]->exists ? '1' : '0');

}]);
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that will still give me a whole row. Also, I don't have a table per se, so I can't use `DB::table`.

Comment: permissions is not a table?

Comment: And you are mistaken, `->select('columnName')` tells laravel to give you a single column, `->take(1)` tells it to fetch a single row.

Comment: It is a table, but if you read my query, the entire thing is in a `EXISTS(*)` clause -- there is no root-level `FROM`.

Comment: So use a DB::raw(). If it's just an "exists", the query itself should return only one column, and Laravel will give you only that. When you run that query directly in your database what do you get?

Comment: `DB::select(DB::raw` gives back an object. To be clear, I want back a string: "0" or "1".

Comment: And you cannot process that result and return exactly what you need? Edited to give you some clues.

Comment: The problem was never whether or not I was capable of getting the result out of Laravel, I was just hoping there was a clean API method for doing this. I will take that as a "no".

Comment: FYI, `$result[0]->exists` will be a "0" or "1" naturally; that's what MySQL returns. No need for a ternary.

Comment: Got it, yeah, probably not. If you need something that specific, you'll have to implement a method in your BaseModel youself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on PostgreSQL and it returns true or false, so I just converted it.

Comment: It returns string "true" or string "false"? Or is the driver smart enough to return a PHP boolean? Because that's what I'm really after. I wouldn't call this very "specific"; even PDO has a built-in `fetchColumn` method for this. It's actually easier to go through that API than Laravel's. Anyway, thanks for your patience.

Comment: It returns `t`, but Laravel converts it to boolean, so I converted it to string (0 & 1), but if you need boolean, just forget about it and avoid that conversion. Anyway, 0,1,true,false in PHP is almost the same `if (1)` is the same as `if (true)`. Specific because not everything is implemented and some stuff are not implemented because you have access to the same information using the usual way. But if you prefer to use PDO in this case, you always can `DB::getPdo()`;